# Prove: In $\mathbb{Z}$, m ~ n iff $|m|=|n|$

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

Prof. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents this exercise:

> Prove that each of the following is an equivalence relation on the indicated set. Then describe the partition associated with that equivalence relation.
>
> In $\mathbb{Z}$, m ~ n iff $|m|=|n|$.

Here's my attempt at the proof.

Given:

> ...---(-2)--(-1)---0---1---2---...

$A_{-2}=2\\
A_{-1}=1\\
A_{0}=0\\
A_{1}=1\\
A_{2}=2$

Observe that $A_{-2} \sim A_2$ and $A_{-1} \sim A_1$.

For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, excluding $0$, $A_{-n} \sim A_n$.

$A_2 \cup A_1 \cup ...=A$
$A_2 \cap A_1 ...=\emptyset$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: You didn't show this was an equivalence relation at all, nor did you describe the partitions.

Comment: Huh? Show symmetric, transitive and reflexive!

Comment: Honestly, I don't say this to mean, your "proof" is completely nonsensical. (sorry!)

Comment: Thank you for the honesty - calling it like it is. Did my proof show that a partition exists? I know that it was **not** my posted question.

Comment: @KevinMeredith You know what the partition looks like (elements of the partition are sets $\{-n,n\}$). You just need to rigorously prove it using set theory language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly $|m|=|m|$. If $|m|=|n|$ then $|n|=|m|$ by the reflexive property of $=$. Finally, if $|m|=|n|$ and $|n|=|p|$ then we have $|m|=|p|$ because $=$ is transitive.

Since $|-n|=|n|$ we have $-n\sim n$. If $m\neq n$ and $m\neq -n$, then $|m|\neq |n|$ so $m\not\sim n$ (this last observation is not a proof, it is only a claim). This is in line with what you were trying to do.

This is sort of a "technical" thing to prove and you could lose sight of what are you trying to show when you go through the proof. Equivalence relations are marvelous things (one use being the decomposition of an arbitray function on a set).

Comment: I'm speculating that using "by the reflexive property of $=$" could be used in many `equivalence relations` proof's, no?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Defining an equivalence relation using others is pretty common! For example, the rationals are defined by an equivalence $\frac{a}{b}\sim \frac{c}{d} \iff ad=bc$ so I would say yes.

Comment: so the partition consists of classes consisting of $\lbrace n, -n \rbrace$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yep, you got it! If we formally define the symbols $[n]$ to be the equivalence class containing $n$, then $[n]=\{n,-n\}$. In this way $\mathbb{Z}$ is partitioned into equivalence classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set and $\sim$ a relation amongst the elements of $X$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation if $\sim$ is symmetric, reflexive and transitive.

Symmetric: $ x \sim y \Rightarrow y \sim x$

Reflexive: $\ x \sim x$

Transitive: $\ x \sim y, y \sim z \Rightarrow x \sim z$.

$\\$

In your example we take $\ \mathbb{Z}/\sim$ where $x \sim y \iff |x| = |y|$.

$\\$

Reflexive: $x \sim x$ since $|x| = |x|$

Symmetric: If $x \sim y$ then $|x|= |y|\ $ so ??

Transitive: ??

$\\$

$\textbf{Two Realizations}$

Some equivalence relations have geometric significance and in this case I believe what this is geometrically is an inifinte collection of tangent unit balls.

[image]

This relation does partitions $\mathbb{Z}$ into intervals of the form $\{-n,n\}$.

$$  \mathbb{Z} = \bigsqcup_{n} \{-n,n\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to describe for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ its class of equivalence and this describe the partition of $Z$ in this case is $n, -n$ so the particion is given by this sets.